# NodeJS - Cant find JSON File

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I'm working on a express API and i want to connect to a mysql server with this api. Settings are stored in a `settings.json` file. I read this using

```
const config = JSON.parse(require(`fs`).readFileSync('../../settings.json'));
```

This works if the json file is in the same directory. But in this case, the settings file is in the base directory(`./settings.json`) but the file from where i want it to access is: `./modules/sql/mysql.js`. It doesnt work:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../../settings.json'
```

Is there a better way to access/read a json file? or what am i doing wrong?

Btw. i dont want to pass the settings as a variable. I already tried it but if possible - i want to avoid it.

**File/Directory strcture**

[image: Directory structure]

Comment: A better approach could be to utilize __dirname and possibly path.join(). There are many ways to approach this but __dirname could help by providing the path to the directory to start with.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky tried it, but get same error

Comment: Update to question to show the updated code. Also show the file structure.

Comment: Please show the path where the script that is running this code is located and the path where the `settings.json` file is located.  We can only help you solve relative path problems if you know the full path (or path to a common named parent) of both items in your current installation.

Comment: We can help you if you shown us the full paths of the two things I asked about in my previous comment.  Without that, all we can do is make wild guesses (which generally aren't productive for anyone) and that means it's an incomplete question.  That's why you're getting downvotes.  Add the necessary info to the question and you will get quick answer.

Comment: i have added a screenshot to demonstrate my file/directory structure

Comment: Why not simply use `require('../../settings.json')`?

Answer (score 0):

did you not miss a ../ there?

try replace '../../settings.json' for '../../../settings.json'

btw, its better to use the __dirname approach, but it should work just fine without that too :)

Comment: the path is correct. i've gone into `/components/sql/` directory using terminal and then used `cat ../../settings.json` and that worked just fine.